# Can I execute a link which executes a function in the Controller and get the data from that Controller via AJAX?

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a list where each listitem contains a link that executes a function in the controller, which fills the viewmodel and returns a partialview. I want to execute that link via Ajax and retrieve the partialview that the controller function returns, but when i execute the ajax function, the controller is not even called. What am i doing wrong here?

Return from the Controller:

```
return PartialView("Oldversiontocandmiddle", model);
```

Ajax call:

```
function retrieveHtmlFromLink() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $("ul.AvailableVersions li a").href,
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function () {
        showProgressAnsicht();
    },
    complete: function () {
        hideProgressAnsicht();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                 $("#jo_contentwrapper").replaceWith(data);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: `$("ul.AvailableVersions li a").href` doesn't return anything. Do `console.log($("ul.AvailableVersions li a").href);` Use `$("ul.AvailableVersions li a").attr('href');`

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't know how to mark your comment as answer, but that worked for me. Thank you!